# Change CSS after ammount of scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to overwrite the CSS code after scrolling `800px` and revert if less than `800`. I have this code:

**Javascript:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 800) {
        $('#nav').css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
    } else {
        $('#nav').attr('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        $('#nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
    } else {
        $('#nav').css('background-color', '');
    }
});
```

You were using `background` instead of `background-color`. You can replace the second property of the else statement with whatever you want it to revert to. The above example will default back to whatever is in the stylesheet.

Here's a working example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tz245uky/3/

Comment: It seems to make sense but still doesnt want to work in my document. my Nav is ofc my menu and its fixed to my screen. Does that make a diffrence?

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your code so I can take a look?

Comment: It should look something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/tz245uky/5/

I added some dummy content to the page so you can see the effect in action.

Comment: It just doesnt want to work for me. Ive tried doing everything in one php document now and also sepperate files...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qtAWreew There is your reformatted code. It's difficult to tell what your problem is without seeing your updated code after the changes.

Comment: IT WORKED. I found an error in my stuff. Thanks for the help!